# Status bar appearing at header image

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I am developing an app compatible with iOS 7. My status bar content like network, battery life etc. appearing at my header image. Please have a look at the screenshot and please guide me how I can resolve this.

** This app is compatible with iOS>=5.0 SDK.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options. For example:

1) You can use iOS 6/7 Deltas in Size inspector while editing your storyboard/nib.

2) You can detect iOS in the code and move all views for

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)

//in viewDidLoad
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0"))
{
    CGRect frame = m_web_view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size.height += 20;
    m_web_view.frame = frame;
}
```

3) You can hide status bar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 -(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

}